# pandas.read_csv converts decimal zero-padded float columns to int

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm storing a Pandas DataFrame in a .csv file which has a column with integer data, but the database system treats as a float for legacy reasons, so the .csv needs to store it as a float too. When storing it with `df.to_csv`, it preserves the zero-padded decimal part, so the column in the .csv file is like:

```
IntNumber
3.0
45.0
123.0
...
```

But when I load this with `pandas.from_csv`, it infers the type as `int64` despite the trailing zero. I've looked through the [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) docs and it looks like I can specify the datatype manually to be `float64`, but I think there are multiple instances of this needing to be detected as `float` instead of `int64`. It would be useful to have it automatically infer the type to be float when the trailing zero is present, is this possible?

Snippet of how I'm loading the csv, at this point it's inferred the type of the column in `dataframe` to be `int64`

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("<csv_name>", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: dataframe = pandas.read_csv("<csv_name>", index_col=0, parse_dates=True).astype(float)
will give you the whole dataframe with type float. As far as I know there is no shorter way to tell pandas which type of values you expect to get.

Comment: I can't replicate this on my end in `0.20.3` but actually I don't doubt it's happening to you because I find `read_csv` datatype inference... unusual. What version are you using?

Comment: I can't replicate on 0.19, I've posted an example. If you can run the script I've provided below on your setup and share the results, then this may help us pinpoint the issue. Also indicate your Pandas version.

Comment: This was an error on my part - I've not been able to reproduce it, I think I've been misreading some of the different instances of the same kind of .csv in my test data. I've voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your issue, see example below.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""IntNumber
3.0
45.0
123.0""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr)

#pandas 0.19.2, python 3.6.0
print(df.dtypes)

IntNumber    float64
dtype: object

#pandas 0.23.1, python 3.6.4
print(df.dtypes)

IntNumber    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem in my Pandas version (0.23.1), but it's possible to be explicit about the types when reading the CSV file by using the `dtype` parameter.

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO


def read_data():
    return StringIO("""IntNumber\n3.0\n45.0\n\n123.0""")

df = pd.read_csv(read_data(), dtype={'IntNumber': np.float32})
print(df.dtypes)

# Output:
# IntNumber    float32
# dtype: object

df = pd.read_csv(read_data(), dtype={'IntNumber': np.int32})
print(df.dtypes)

# Output:
# IntNumber    int32
# dtype: object
```